# Facing issue with infinite scroll using ionic 2/3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Here i m consuming dynamic data with parameter i applied the infinite scrolling but the items didn't show on my scroll page below is my code:

**.html**

```
  <ion-list class="_list" *ngFor="let ifo of IData;"  (click)="go(ifo.Id,ifo.Name)"   >

<ion-item class="itm">
      <ion-avatar item-start role="img">
        <img [src]="'data:image/png;base64,'+ifo.Image" style="width: 110px;">
      </ion-avatar>

      <div class="item-inner">
        <h2 class="_nme">{{ifo.Name}}</h2>
        <p class="_price">{{ifo.Cost}}</p>
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
      </div>

    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

     <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

below is my ts code :

```
getAllData(id){     
    const toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'Unable to get data',
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });

    this.serv.Get(id).subscribe(res =>{
      loading.dismiss();

      this.iData = res.GetResult;
      console.log(this.iData);


    },err=>{
       toast.present();
    })

  }




doInfinite(infiniteScroll) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');

    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        this.iData.push( this.iData.length );
      }

      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      infiniteScroll.complete();
    }, 500);
  }
```

actually upto that soup item only the list is there even though there is no list it is displaying empty images and list
[image: ItemsData]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because you repeat `ion-list` instead of `ion-item`. The example from docs:

[image]

You should do the following:

```
<ion-list class="_list">
  <ion-item class="itm" *ngFor="let ifo of IData" (click)="go(ifo.Id,ifo.Name)">CONTENT OF ITEM GOES HERE</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The idea is to **repeat items** inside **one container**. And here is the ref to [**docs**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) for more info.

**P.S.**: I'm also not sure, do you have `ion-content` wrapper element, in most cases we have to include it to force the ion stuff to work. If you don't have yet, please, include it as shown on screenshot.

Comment: Yeah i have the ion-content wrapper

Comment: Yeah i tried the solutions and it is not working same after the list of the items it is displaying the empty list

Comment: @Madpop did you check the console? Do you have all necessary data and you just can't see it in the view?

Comment: I tried another approach using setting the pagenumbers and it worked

Comment: Cool! Please, share the working solution to allow other users to fix such issues